# Is there a name for the kinds of sets of equations that don't have a functional form? $f(x)$ can't represent a circle, for example.

Tags: geometry, functions, terminology, circles

Do the kinds of systems that can be put into functional form have a specific name? What about the ones that cannot be put into functional form?

For example, a circle can be expressed as $x^2 + y^2 = 1$, but there's not a functional form. On the other hand lines can be expressed as $f(x) = mx + b$ where $y = f(x)$. Do these have different names?

Comment: So you want a name for those equations where there are different y-values for a single x-value ?

Comment: In general, we just call them relations.

Comment: @insipidintegrator that sounds like a more concise way to state what I'm looking for.

Comment: @SeanRoberson thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generalization of a [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_%28mathematics%29) which allows for multiple $y$ values per $x$ value would be a [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_%28mathematics%29). But every function is also a binary relation. To explicitly denote the case that's not a function, I'd call that a “non-functional binary relation”.

The term “functional” denotes a binary relation where there is at most one $y$ for each $x$. It thus corresponds to a [partial function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_function). A total function could be called a left-total functional binary relation; it implies that for each $x$ there is exactly one $y$ in the relation. A non-functional binary relation would thus be one that's not even a partial function, so it has to have at least two $y$ for at least one $x$.

Comment: This looks like the answer I needed. Thank you for linking to wikipedia and giving me context to read it!